# Error while using ARC + Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

Here are the steps to reproduce:

Using Xcode 4.2 create a new project using **Master-Detail Application**

**Check Use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), Core Data and select iPad**
.
Inside `viewDidLoad` put this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(goBack)]; 
backButton.title = @"back";
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Also put this method somewhere else:

```
- (void)goBack
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` on `MasterViewController` put this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MasterViewController* master = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
    master.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:master animated:YES];  
}
```

Add a line and click inside it.

Go back to the main view and click again in the item.

Try to add something or delete in the new view and the following crash occurs:

```
*** -[MasterViewController controllerWillChangeContent:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6d85c30
```

The same steps don't occur if you don't use ARC.

Same error using a modal.

Can anyone confirm this or I'm missing something with the use of ARC?

Comment: What stack trace do you get when it crashes?

Comment: *** -[MasterViewController controllerWillChangeContent:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6d85c30

Comment: this scenario (while odd) works fine under ARC. Have you made other changes not reflected here? Generally, ARC causes any object not retained somewhere to be released at the end of a run loop. Your error suggests that you made a change that is assigning the wrong MasterViewController as a delegate of a fetchedResultsController so a deallocated Master is being sent a delegate message. If you want more help, post some more code.

Comment: The difference was the option "Enable Zombie Objects" in the scheme editor was enabled, causing the bug. Very strange!

Comment: Thanks, it seems that disabling zombie objects I solved my same problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that enabling zombies with core data causes a few problems, best advice i can give is to enable it only when necessary.